# Sammy.js + Bootstrap collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sammy.js

I use Sammy.js on site and when i reflesh (ctrl+f5) collapse (Bootstrap) always shown.
some code:
 Html

```
 <h5><a class="subCat-h5" data-toggle="collapse-next" title="{{Page}}">{{subCat}}</a></h5>
 <div class="collapse">
```

Sammy.js

```
  this.get("#!/page/:page", function() {
    var page = this.params['page'];
    $('#premain').empty();
    this.render('templates/main.mustache', {"contentId":page})
                .replace("#main");
        $('.triple-div').removeClass('active-menu');
            $('#menu_' + page).addClass('active-menu');
        $('h5').next().collapse('hide');    
        $('.active-menu:contains(Черный металлопрокат)').each(function(){$('h5:contains(Черный металлопрокат)').next().collapse('show')});
        $('.active-menu:contains(Нержавеющий металлопрокат)').each(function(){$('h5:contains(Нержавеющий металлопрокат)').next().collapse('show')});
        $('.active-menu:contains(Цветной металлопрокат)').each(function(){$('h5:contains(Цветной металлопрокат)').next().collapse('show')});
```

You can see it on m-chel.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Need add:

```
$(".collapse").collapse({toggle: false});
```

Before:

```
$('h5').next().collapse('hide');
```

And it all ok.